# Cypress & Google Maps dragging moves elements, not the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cypress

I am trying to write a test in Cypress (v8):

1. When the map loads, we hit an endpoint `/myFleet` to generate markers.
2. Then, the user drags the map.  And `onDragEnd`, we display a button to "Search Area"
3. When user clicks "Drag Area" we again `cy.intercept` the `/myFleet` endpoint.

When I attempt item 2, the Search Area button & the Google Maps zoom controls move "up" the X-axis the same amount as my `mousemove` event & the `click()` on the search button does not get triggered.

```
cy.get('#live-view-map')
      .trigger('mousedown')
      .trigger('mousemove', { x: 261, y: 0 })
      .trigger('mouseup')
      .wait(500); // just to allow google maps tiles to resettle after drag

    cy.findByTestId('button-search-area').click();
```

Here is a GIF: https://recordit.co/B6H5iWEyK5

and Here is a screen shot of "AFTER": [image]

Why does my button & google zoom control move up?  I think it's interfering in being able to actually select & click the element.

Am I not selecting the correct element to drag (`cy.get('#live-view-map')`)?

Answer (score 1):

it appears the reason it was not moving the map is because the map wasn't fully loaded.  The Zoom controls were missing in the UI after further review.  So, by adding a check to find the buttons, we know the map has settled.

```
cy.findByRole('button', {
      name: /zoom out/i,
    });
    cy.get('#live-view-map')
      .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })
      .trigger('mousemove', { which: 1, x: 261, y: 0 })
      .trigger('mouseup')
      .wait(500);
    cy.findByTestId('button-search-area').click();
```

In the new video, you can see Cypress rendering the map with some bouncing around of elements but now it's more predictable.